# Function behaves differently in Jest than it does in the app

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am trying to test a simple function in Jest that compares 2 strings. If they are equal the function should return true. If not it should return false.

It looks like this:

```js
export const validateInput = (dispatch) => {
  return (userInput, expected) => {
  if (userInput === expected) {
      navigate('done')
      return true
  }
  else{
    dispatch({ type: 'error_message', payload: 'your seed phrase was not typed correctly'})
    return false
    }
  }
}
```

When I use it in Jest like this:

```
it('gives valid and invalid input to validateInputPhrase', () => {
        const userInput = 'blouse'
        const expected = 'hello'
        expect(validateInput(userInput, expected)).toBeTruthy()
        expect(validateInput(userInput, 'blouse')).toBeTruthy()
    })
```

Jest is saying that in both cases it is truthy, even though 'blouse' is clearly not equal to 'hello'.

Does anyone see the problem here and why the function `validateInput` always resolves to truthy in the test?

Comment: Your function _returns a function_, which is always truthy. `.toBeTruthy` is a terrible expectation in general - `.toBe(true)` would show a failure _and why_.